# What does choosing a Post Page do?

Tags: homepage, frontpage

I have always been confused by Wordpress's homepage setting, even though I have read some SO answers and [WordPress front page logic cheatsheet](https://www.rarst.net/wordpress/front-page-logic/).

First of all I understand the different between "latest post" and "a static page", so this is not the problem. The problem is with two types of "static page". It seems to me if you have set a page for "Homepage", then the setting of "Post page" is of no use and can be ignored. Is this understanding right? Also I check some of my sites and found that when "Homepage" is not selected, no matter what page you set for "Post page" the Front page will remain the same.

So I'm confused here. Why will choosing a "Post page" be useful?

Comment: The "post page" is useful if you're using WordPress as a blog. If you set the Post Page to a page, that page's content (if any) will be replaced with a list of the most recent posts in your site.

Answer (score 1):

> Why will choosing a "Post page" be useful?

Because if your homepage is a static page, where will the main post archive go? It no longer exists, but you can bring it back by choosing a posts page. You do this by choosing a `page` that has the URL you want, and that URL wll become the posts page, overriding that `page`.

Note that when you choose a post page, that feature takes over that `page`, and it is no longer used as a `page`. You can't for example give the *posts page* a page template, or set its content. The posts page feature overrides that functionality and replaces it for that URL.